# Selecting GROUP whose MEMBERS are all aged under X

Tags: mysql, sql

As an example, I'm trying to select a group in which all of its members are aged under a certain age.

If I had a table like this:

```
name | group | age
andy | 1     | 15
lisa | 1     | 16
matt | 2     | 24
...  | 3     | 15
...  | 3     | 26
```

Selecting the group with members all aged 17 or under would return group 1.

I've tried using GROUP BY... HAVING... clauses, but that returns group 1 and group 3, since group 3 has a member aged 15.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to count the members of each group, and also count the number of members who aged 17 or under. For a group where all the members are under 17, these counts will be the same. In MySQL you can do the latter with `SUM(age <= 17)` since MySQL treats booleans as 1 or 0 in a numeric context:

```
SELECT `group`
FROM groups
GROUP BY `group`
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(age <= 17)
```

Output

```
group
1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3SKjBB3WrTDkZQh1pZUi4i/0)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for the edit I had misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by looking at the maximum age:

```
SELECT `group`
FROM groups
GROUP BY `group`
HAVING MAX(age) <= 17;
```

Note:  This assumes that `age` is never `NULL`.  If that is a possibility, you should explain what logic you want to handle `NULL` values.

I should also note that in most circumstances like this, you would have a separate table of groups.  If that is the case, then `not exists` is probably the most efficient solution:

```
select g.*
from groups g
where not exists (select 1
                  from groupmembers gm
                  where gm.groupid = g.groupid and
                        gm.age > 17
                 );
```

This has the advantage of getting all groups that meet the conditions you state, even those with no members.